# Using sanitize functions in PageDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagedown

I have an issue with using `getSanitizingConverter()`.When I try to use the following code:

```
var plainText;
var markdown = new Markdown.Converter();
var markdown = getSanitizingConverter();

plainText = markdownConverter.makeHtml("#Hi");

$(".hello").html(plainText);
```

I get an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: getSanitizingConverter is not defined`

My HTML:

```
<script src="markdown/converter.js"></script>
<script src="markdown/sanitizer.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Here is a codepen [RTC](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CemLj/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `getSanitizingConverter` function is placed on the Markdown variable. Try this:

```
var plainText;
var markdown = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();

plainText = markdown.makeHtml("#Hi");

$(".hello").html(plainText);
```

Comment: Sweet! Works great. No sure why they didn't put that in their docs. https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown

Comment: Ya. The docs seem incorrect. I had to dig into the source to figure out what was going on